# What does self.model(batch) do in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently rewriting a PyTorch code to tensorflow. During this I found a line that I don't understand, so I am not able to translate it to tensorflow.

Can someone explain me what this does/ means?

```
self.model(batch)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like `self.model` is a layer/layers of a neural network, derived from `nn.Module` class.
The call `self.model(batch)` invoke's `self.model`'s `__call__` method with the argument `batch`.
If you inspect closely, `nn.Module.__call__` do some "bookkeeping" but essentially, it calls the `self.model`'s `forward` function.